# Use pure gulp instead of elixir in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, gulp

I'm very new with laravel, previously I was on node.js mostly.

We use react with laravel in a new project. I'm confused when I saw this file https://github.com/eriksape/laravel-react-hot-loader/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Why use elixir in gulpfile.js? I thought we can do the gulp way like

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync({ 
        proxy: 'localhost:8000',
        middleware: [
        webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
          publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,

          stats: { colors: true }

        }),

        webpackHotMiddleware(bundler)
      ]
    });
});
```

But I did tried to use pure gulp, the hot reloading did not work, webpack will bundle everything from scratch again. I wonder what role does elixir is doing here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Elixir, then you don't have to worry about anything.

Just remove references to it and ad your gulp dependencies in your `package.json` file, and then execute `gulp` as you would normally.

Comment: I tried it doesn't work. The browsersync worked but wepack will bundle everything again.

Comment: @Mellisa How will Webpack do anything? If you don't have any reference to webpack in your gulp file, it will not execute anything. Can I see the entirety of your Gulpfile please?